# AttributeError: type object 'ES' has no attribute 'bSizer1'

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I have a nested class and a base class, when I try to add a panel to a sizer, it adds the panel but gives this error: "AttributeError: type object 'ES' has no attribute 'bSizer1'"

I have two files:

gui.py

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

ID_YENI_BINA = 1000
ID_YENI_MTERI = 1001

class ES ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )



        self.bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.SetSizer( self.bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()
        self.m_menubar1 = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
        self.lemler = wx.Menu()
        self.yeni = wx.Menu()
        self.yeniBina = wx.MenuItem( self.yeni, ID_YENI_BINA, u"Yeni Bina", wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.yeni.AppendItem( self.yeniBina )

        self.yeniMteri = wx.MenuItem( self.yeni, ID_YENI_MTERI, u"Yeni Müşteri", wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.yeni.AppendItem( self.yeniMteri )

        self.lemler.AppendSubMenu( self.yeni, u"Yeni" )

        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.lemler, u"İşlemler" ) 

        self.SetMenuBar( self.m_menubar1 )

        self.m_statusBar1 = self.CreateStatusBar( 1, wx.ST_SIZEGRIP, wx.ID_ANY )

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.getirYeniBinaFnk, id = self.yeniBina.GetId() )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.yeniMusteriGetir, id = self.yeniMteri.GetId() )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def getirYeniBinaFnk( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

class yeniBina ( wx.Panel ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 451,363 ), style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        gSizer1 = wx.GridSizer( 8, 2, 0, 0 )

        self.m_staticText1 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Bina İsmi:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText1.Wrap( -1 )
        gSizer1.Add( self.m_staticText1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_textCtrl1 = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        gSizer1.Add( self.m_textCtrl1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( gSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

    def __del__( self ):
        pass
```

EmlakProES.py

```
import wx
from gui import ES

from gui import yeniBina
from gui import yeniMusteri


class EmlakProES( ES ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        ES.__init__( self, parent )

    def getirYeniBinaFnk( self, event ):
        panel = yeniBina(self)

        ES.bSizer1.Add(panel,1, wx.EXPAND)
        ES.SetSizer(ES.bSizer1)
        self.Fit()
        self.Show()

        pass

app = wx.App(0)
EmlakProES(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I do not know where I'm wrong but I appreciate if anyone points where and explains how should it works. Thanks

Comment: Could you reduce this to a [mcve], please? Also, follow [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and consider using `super` (e.g. `super(EmlakProES, self).__init__(parent)`).

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code:

```
class EmlakProES( ES ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        ES.__init__( self, parent )

    def getirYeniBinaFnk( self, event ):
        panel = yeniBina(self)

        ES.bSizer1.Add(panel,1, wx.EXPAND)
        ES.SetSizer(ES.bSizer1)
```

The name `ES` refers to the `ES` *class* (Python's classes are objects too), while `bSizer` is an *instance* attribute - hence the `AttributeError`.

Now since `EmlakProES` inherits from `ES` and you correctly calls `ES.__init__()` from `EmlakProES.__init__()`, your `EmlakProES` instance does have a `bSizer1` instance attribute, so you can just access it on the current instance (`self`), ie:

```
    def getirYeniBinaFnk( self, event ):
        panel = yeniBina(self)

        self.bSizer1.Add(panel,1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(ES.bSizer1)
```